# 16.04 Oct 10 update breaks wifi and libkmod

Tags: 16.04, broadcom, modprobe

I've tried dozens of advices, mostly from askubuntu, about disabling secure boot, purging and reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source, followed guide for signing bcmwl-kernel-source, tried changing bcmwl-kernel-source for fcutterb43, etc. Nothing is working. No wifi after yesterday's update.

Whenever I reboot, I see this in the consoles -- though it flashes by really fast. Whenever I install something or update/upgrade, I see this. Whenever I do anything about modprobe or install bcmwl-kernel-source, this is the culprit:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper'
```

When running $ sudo modprobe wl I get the above, plus:

```
 libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper' modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-42-generic
```

Dell 13" 9350
BCM4350 broadcom wireless

More info per @Chili555 's request:

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper'
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`

```
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
drm_kms_helper
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
```

Comment: It is unclear what wireless module you have and what you did.

Comment: It is not `w1` with a one; it is `wl` with an L. What is the result of: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: tom::~$ sudo modprobe wl

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper'
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-42-generic

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Also: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`

Comment: chili555 Thank you for helping, added those details to the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this `local.conf` by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

This file has a wrong format.

If you really need this setting (I have no idea why you added it), the correct format of that file is

```
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
```

You need to remove the first two lines.

Regarding the wireless adapter do not install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. This adapter is supported by `brcmfmac` in kernels 4.4+. It may be blocked by `rfkill` though.