# New kind of "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, lightdm

Hello everybody my first post here.

Specs: Intel Core i5-6200U 4GB RAM 128GB SSD

Ubuntu 16.04 user here.

So before my laptop messed up when I edited the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file [in reference to this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451526/removing-guest-session-at-login-in-ubuntu-14-04) as I wanted to remove the Ubuntu guest session. I added this text to the file `allow-guest=false`and saved.

Since the next restart I am now stuck with the error "The system is running in low-graphics mode". However, looking through forums I have not been able to find a solution suggested by others in the comments.

When trying to load the recovery menu (by holding shift) it does nothing and carry's on and boots into the error. Once in the error I cannot carry out any of the options such as "Edit configuration file" as it just doesn't open.

Other solutions were to get into a command line using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> which also does not work (does nothing) and exiting to the console login just gives me this.

[image: img]

And does nothing after. Others are saying that this issue could be disk size related however, I had around 100GB+ storage space available.

I thought maybe I could boot into BIOS and re-install Ubuntu however, I cannot seem to get access to it. Have tried booting and using keys <kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd>.

For more context I have made a short [video](https://youtu.be/sz4QPOmiXfI) recording the problems I am having.

Hope someone can help me.

EDIT: `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`

```
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
```

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
allow-guest=false
```

EDIT 2:

[image: img]

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` and I'll take a look for you. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Comment: ps: and `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: [Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835701/16-04-oct-10-update-breaks-wifi-and-libkmod) people suggest removing `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` as a solution. But again you need to boot into some kind of live USB so that you can mount your file-system and make changes to it. To get into BIOS, you need to press one of F keys (try them all) the instant computer comes up and [repeatedly pressing it](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500216) at least five to ten times.

Comment: If your keyboard has secondary F keys which it looks like it does from the video, you should hold the `Fn` key first and then start hitting F keys.

Comment: @darksky Your advice worked I finally managed to get into the bios. Now we can get somewhere. I can't believe I did not realise this.

Comment: I have now booted from a live USB and mounted my filesystem. I have now added the two outputs of the files you have requested @heynnema

Comment: Editing the two files. Removing "allow-guest=false" from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and removing "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" from the /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf has allowed me to now boot normally again.

Comment: @Dextroz good news. There's nothing wrong with the "allow-guest=false" statement... it was the "options..." one that did it. Lets check one thing just for fun... `lsmod | grep -i drm_kms_helper` and lets see if this kernel module is loaded.

Comment: @Dextroz ps: I just reviewed your lightdm.conf, and the "allow..." did cause a problem, because you're missing two things that are missing in the .conf file... [LightDM]
[SeatDefaults] (each on separate lines) should have come before the "allow..."

Comment: @heynnema edit 2 has the following info you requested for fun :-) thanks for all the help everybody I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

**Problem #1:**

Adding "allow-guest=false" to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` resulted in an incomplete `lightdm.conf` file. The correct file should look like this:

```
[LightDM]
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
```

**Problem #2:**

An invalid or incompatible options statement for the video driver was added to `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`. Removing "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" solved it.