# Libkmod error - Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't start

Tags: 18.04, modprobe

While starting the system I'm getting the following message:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:
/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'drm_kms_helper'
```

The contents of the file was:

```
drm_kms_helper
options drm_kms_helper poll=N
```

I deleted this file and tried no luck.
I also edited this file with only the second line and deleted first line as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835701/16-04-oct-10-update-breaks-wifi-and-libkmod).

Nothing works and the system doesn't open the GUI startup. How can I fix this issue?